# Regex to match specific sentence in a string

Tags: python, xml, string

I need to write a regex to catch this sentence (to remove it in Python):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

I tried writing this one (on a regex tester), but doesn't work:

`(<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>)`

Does anybody know how to help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python regex you need to escape double quotes:

```
(<\?xml version=\"1\.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\?>)
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/8DE0pl/1)